# how can I get field and value from nested array and query them to find doc in mongodb?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongodb-query, nosql-aggregation

I am trying to get field and values from a nested array which is dynamic(List1 and List2 ar dynamic )

```
let selectionCritea = {
  List1: [ 'mk singh', 'saurav kashsyap' ],
  List2: [
    { labelName: 'Location', values: ['India','America','Japan'] },
    { labelName: 'gender', values: ['male'] }
  ]
}
```

I want to find doc from db which has properties as "labelname" and values from corresponding "values" array
i.e. gender is male and Location is either India ,America or Japan.
here is my modelschema:

```
{ "_id" : "6123e7ahdhdfdj334733",
    "name" : "Mohit Kumar",
    "gender" : "male",
    "Location" : "India",
    },
   { "_id" : "6123e7ahdhdfdj334731",
    "name" : "saurav  Kashyap",
    "gender" : "male",
    "Location" : "Nepal",
    },
   { "_id" : "6123e7ahdhdfdj334720",
    "name" : "Shaline",
    "gender" : "female",
    "Location" : "america",
    },
```

so I should get only first doc because gender is male and location in from values array.
I have tried all my knowledge but couldnot get it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all you need to prepare a query in client side,

```js
let selectionCritea = {
  List1: [ 'mk singh', 'saurav kashsyap' ],
  List2: [
    { labelName: 'Location', values: ['India','America','Japan'] },
    { labelName: 'gender', values: ['male'] }
  ]
}
let query = {};

// get regular expression query condition
let names = [];
selectionCritea.List1.forEach(q => {
  names.push(q)
})
if(names.length) {
  query.name = { $regex: names.join("|") }
}

// prepare List2 conditions
selectionCritea.List2.forEach(q => {
  query[q.labelName] = (Array.isArray(q.values) ? { $in: q.values } : q.values);
})

console.log(query)
```

You can use the above prepared query in find query:

```
db.collection.find(query);
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/gAMrkOh8MG4)